# WP: accessing a $wpdb associative array and send it with json

Tags: arrays, wordpress, associative

I'm working on an AJAX session that calls (successfully) a PHP function:

```
$coordList = WM_Db_Cantine_Speaker::get_lat_lng();
```

The static method get_lat_lng() uses $wpdb to query a database and returns an associative array. Through var_dump I got the following structure:

```
array(2) { 
 [0]=> array(2) { 
    ["latitudine"]=> string(9) "45.340245" 
    ["longitudine"]=> string(9) "11.648950" 
 } 
 [1]=> array(2) { 
    ["latitudine"]=> string(9) "45.328472" 
    ["longitudine"]=> string(9) "11.715512" 
 } 
}
```

This is the whole code:

```
function get_coordinates(){
var coordinate;
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : wmAjaxObj.ajaxurl,
            data : { action : "wm_get_lat_lng" /*, imageID : attachment.id */ }, /* imageID verrà passato a PHP con $_POST['imageID'] */
            success : function(response){
                if( response.type == "success" ){
                    coordinate = response.coordList;
                }//if
                else{
                    alert('AJAX error');
                }//else
            }//success
    }); //ajax
} );
return coordinate;
}//get_coordinates


function wm_get_lat_lng(){

    //get an associative array of coordinates
    $coordList = WM_Db_Cantine_Speaker::get_lat_lng();

    echo json_encode(array(
        'type' => 'success',
        'coordList' => $coordList
    ), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    die(0);
}//wm_get_lat_lng
add_action('wp_ajax_wm_get_lat_lng', 'wm_get_lat_lng');
```

How can I get "latitudine" and "longitudine" values for each element?

And how can I send it using json for jQuery management after the AJAX call?
Thank you so much

Comment: Have you already registered a callback in javascript?

Comment: I edit the post so you can see the whole code. Thank you

Comment: Looks correct at first sight. Where exactly do you get stuck? Do you get the return from your callback in js? Keep in mind that the callback will only be available in the dashboard, otherwise you would need to additionally add: `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wm_get_lat_lng', 'wm_get_lat_lng');`

Comment: The problem I'm facing just now is to get the array from get_coordinates() to another javascript field (a template page. I tried to pass different data and it works)

Comment: So get_coordinates() returns the data but you can't access it in another scope (for example inline js)? What you could try is to make the `coordinate` variable a global by initiating it outside the function definition: `var coordinate; function get_coordinates(){...}`

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. I mean, I tried with a string: I declared it global (in a different js file because the AJAX call is in a different js file) and I couldn't print it from another file (a template)

Answer (score 0):

AJAX call and the place where I needed the array where in different files.
I resolved putting the AJAX call on the same file where the array's needed.